Extract LESS without transpiling to CSS
I am using Rollup to build a Frontend Library. This library uses Less for styling. The current setup postprocesses the Less and extracts it into a CSS file. This CSS file is then imported by users of the library.
This works fine but has limitations. For example, it is not possible to modify Less variables from outside the Library, since their values are already hard-coded into the CSS. I would like to fix this by extracting the Less into a single file instead of extracting the CSS.
It does NOT work to simply find all .less files and concatenating them into a single file because this breaks imports.
Also: I use CSS/Less modules quite extensively, so these need to work aswell.
Currently, I am using the plugin rollup-plugin-postcss but I am open to using another one.

It's not clear what the difference is between "extracting the less into a single file" and "concatenating the less into a single file". Clearly the latter doesn't work so what would have to happen in the former to make it work? Perhaps you could add a little more detail to your question to help those who try to answer.
